# GLFW | What is a frame?

Tags: opengl

[Here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_swap_buffers) I was reading about buffers and found such text:

> When the entire frame has been rendered, the buffers need to be swapped with one another, so the back buffer becomes the front buffer and vice versa.

And also this

> The swap interval indicates how many frames to wait until swapping the buffers, commonly known as vsync.

The question is: what is a frame? And how does it differ from buffer?

Comment: The "frame" will just refer to the image data while the "buffer" will be the memory used to store it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, a frame is the image you're trying to create, presumably for the purpose of display. It is the product of your entire rendering operation for a specific slice of time.

A "buffer" is the memory *for* the image you either are trying to create or have already created. Hence the common term: framebuffer. Indeed, the choice of the word "buffer" is because you are typically *buffering* multiple images. That is, one buffer will currently be in the process of being displayed, while another buffer is being rendered.